# I am unable to use all methods of assert even after i have import the library of asserts and have all dependencies

Tags: selenium, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYiGv.jpg)

I am unable to use all methods of assert even after i have import the library of asserts and have all dependencies

Comment: What is the version of TestNG that you are using into your project? Also, preferably for assertions, please use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core .

Comment: Your import has failed. See red underline. Fix it and you'll find all method of TestNG asserts.